# Get Recording Video Raw frames

Tags: ios, image-processing, video-processing, ca

I am new to Objective-C and iOS technology.I want to **record the video through code** and during run time, I have to get each frame as raw data for some processing.How can I achieve this? Please any one help me. Thanks in Advance. Here is my code so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setupCaptureSession];

}
```

The viewDidAppear function

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (!_bpickeropen)
    {
       _bpickeropen = true;
        _picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        _picker.delegate = self;
        NSArray *sourceTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:picker.sourceType];
        if (![sourceTypes containsObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie ])
        {
            NSLog(@"device not supported");
            return;
        }

        _picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        _picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,nil];//,(NSString *) kUTTypeImage
        _picker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
        [self presentModalViewController:_picker animated:YES];
    }



}
```

// Delegate routine that is called when a sample buffer was written

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{

    CVImageBufferRef cameraFrame = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);


    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);

    GLubyte *rawImageBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraFrame);

    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cameraFrame);

    **NSData *dataForRawBytes = [NSData dataWithBytes:rawImageBytes length:bytesPerRow * CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraFrame)];
```

**

**PROBLEMS**
1.(Here i am getting the raw bytes only once)
2.(After that i want to store this raw bytes as binary file in app path).

```
// Do whatever with your bytes

NSLog(@"bytes per row %zd",bytesPerRow);

[dataForRawBytes writeToFile:[self datafilepath]atomically:YES];

NSLog(@"Sample Buffer Data is %@\n",dataForRawBytes);


CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);
```

}

here i am setting the delegate of output// Create and configure a capture session and start it running
- (void)setupCaptureSession
{
    NSError *error = nil;

```
// Create the session
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];


// Configure the session to produce lower resolution video frames, if your
// processing algorithm can cope. We'll specify medium quality for the
// chosen device.
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

// Find a suitable AVCaptureDevice
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice
                           defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

// Create a device input with the device and add it to the session.
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device
                                                                    error:&error];
if (!input)
{
    // Handling the error appropriately.
}
[session addInput:input];

// Create a VideoDataOutput and add it to the session
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
[session addOutput:output];


// Configure your output.
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
[output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
dispatch_release(queue);

// Specify the pixel format
output.videoSettings =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
                            forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey]; //kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey


// If you wish to cap the frame rate to a known value, such as 15 fps, set
// minFrameDuration.
// output.minFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 15);

// Start the session running to start the flow of data
[session startRunning];

// Assign session to an ivar.
//[self setSession:session];
```

}

I appreciate any help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into the `AVFoundation` framework. It allows you access to the raw data generated from the camera.

This [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) is a good intro-level project to the AVFoundation video camera usage.

In order to get individual frames from the video output, you could use the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` class from the AVFoundation framework.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: You could look at the delegate functions of `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`, in particular the `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` method. This will be called every time a new frame is captured.

If you do not know how delegates work, this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm) is a good example of delegates.

Comment: yes i am used the AVFoundation frame work for this.But i don't know how and where to call the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.Because my camera record keep on recording but i am getting the raw bytes only once.But i want to keep on get from my camera.So how can i use the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput in efficient way.After getting the raw bytes from that i have to get the binary format of that raw bytes of my frame also.So please help me how can i achieve that one also.Thanks lot for you'r interesting.

Comment: Hi Tcharni,My functionalities of classes like this.Give me some more idea also.

Comment: Hey, I edited my answer and added a possible solution to your problem. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I kept one count value in that function and i am keep on incrementing the count value in captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection: in this method but the count value remaining same. ya i am using what u told the delegate of AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate but here i am getting the raw bytes only once.But my doubt is i want to get the raw bytes of each and every recording frames and I want to sotre that raw bytes into binary format and i have to store to the app memory please @tcharni help me for this one only.I have a hope u know more well in this topic.

Comment: - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{

    NSLog(@"<<<<<<<<<<<<<Count is  = %d>>>>>>>>>>",count++);
    CVImageBufferRef cameraFrame = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    
    
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);
    
    GLubyte *rawImageBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraFrame);
    
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cameraFrame);
    
   }

Comment: The only thing that I can see you missing, is that you haven't set self as the delegate of AVCaptureVideoDataOutput, and you haven't set it as implementing the required protocol

Comment: // Create and configure a capture session and start it running
- (void)setupCaptureSession
{
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [session addOutput:output];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
    dispatch_release(queue);
    
} here i am setting the delegate of that.

Comment: I am added the delegate in separate function.

Comment: Ok, change NULL to DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, and don't release the queue.

Comment: i changed like this    // Configure your output.
    dispatch_queue_t queue = DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL ;//dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [_output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue]; then i am getting this error  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:queue:] - NULL sampleBufferCallbackQueue passed.'
*** First throw call stack:
//    dispatch_release(queue);

Comment: dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL ); This was what I meant

Comment: i got one point when ever i mentioned my pikerimagecontroller source is   _picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo,nil]; instead of KUTTypeMovie then it's calling that output delegate but it's not showing the camera recorder view what's the reason behind this then how can we solve this

Comment: Oh, the problem is that you are trying to use UIImagePicker's video camera output, with AVFoundation CaptureVideoData. You have to set up a session of AVCaptureSession. Follow the code given in the code sample.

Comment: which sample i have to follow? please tell me.Really i didn't understand the concept of UIImagePicker and AVFoundation CaptureVideoData.

Comment: Follow the AVCam example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html